# Java Generics Comparable with Inheritance

Tags: generics, inheritance, warnings, comparable

I would like to override a abstract method as follows:

```
abstract <C extends Comparable<C>> Map<String, Function<E, C>> getSortingMap();
```

The Method overwritten looks like that:

```
@Override
Map<String, Function<Contract, Comparable<?>>> getSortingMap() {
    final Map<String, Function<Contract, Comparable<?>>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(Contract.APPRENTICE, e -> e.getApprentice().getLastName()); // String
    map.put(Contract.COMPANY, e -> e.getCompany().getName()); // Name Object
    map.put(Contract.EDUCATION_END, e -> e.getEducationEnd()); // Calendar
    map.put(Contract.STATUS, e -> e.getStatus()); // ENUM
    return map;
}
```

I have a warning I would like gone without supress warning, because I guess there must be a clean solution:

```
Type safety: The return type Map<String,Function<Contract,Comparable<?
     >>> for getSortingMap() from the type ContractIntegrationTest needs unchecked 
     conversion to conform to Map<String,Function<Contract,Comparable>> from the type 
     _AbstractFinderServiceIntegrationTest<Contract,ContractFilter,ContractSearch>
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: make your abstract method have a signature:

`abstract Map<String, Function<E, Comparable<?>>> getSortingMap();`

Long answer:

Looking at the signature of the abstract method, I can't see where the type parameter E is specified, so I guess that's the type parameter of the class.

`abstract class MyClass<E>`

and the child class is then

`class ChildClass extends MyClass<Contract>`

Having said that, the signatures

`<C extends Comparable<C>> List<C> doSomething();`

and simply

`List<Comparable<?>> doSomething();`

return different things (I use lists here instead of maps of functions as in your example for simplicity, the idea is the same).

In order to call the first one, you need to pass the exact type of the comparable. So for example

`List<String> stringList= doSomething();//method with <C>`

You get the list of strings, can add strings to it, remove from it etc.

However the second one returns you a list which can hold any kind of comparable.

`List<Comparable<?>> comparables = doSomething();//method with <?>`

And you can add any comparable there you want. You can't parametrize it with String. And if you take something from the list, you will get `Comparable<?>` back.

You can't assign stringList to comparables nor vice versa - these things are simply different.